# What happens for hive local database in flutter after updating app in app store?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm new i flutter. I'm developing an offline money management app. I used hive as local database of my app for storing data locally. I have one important question: if I release new update after publishing my app in the app store,
what happens for hive local database in flutter after update? Does my users will lost their registered data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the app does not change or delete it's data on a device.

However, you are responsible to ensure the new version of the app can read and update the database successfully if you add or remove fields, type, tables, etc.

The is best ensured by suitable test cases that can be run before each release.